# How to get data-value, which class="rb-tab-active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some question about how to get `data-value` from `<div>` if the "class" is "rb-tab-active".

```
                    <p>B. Demonstrasi</p>
                    <div class="rb" id="rb-2">
                      <div class="rb-tab" data-value="1">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Sangat Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" data-value="2">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" data-value="3">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Cukup Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" data-value="4">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Kurang</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" data-value="5">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Tidak Sama Sekali</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('.rb-tab-active').data('value')`.

Further reading:-

1. [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
2. [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
<p>B. Demonstrasi</p>
<div class="rb" id="rb-2">
  <div class="rb-tab" data-value="1">
    <div class="rb-spot">
      <span class="rb-txt">Sangat Besar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rb-tab" data-value="2">
    <div class="rb-spot">
      <span class="rb-txt">Besar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rb-tab" data-value="3">
    <div class="rb-spot">
      <span class="rb-txt">Cukup Besar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rb-tab-active" data-value="4">
    <div class="rb-spot">
      <span class="rb-txt">Kurang</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rb-tab-active" data-value="5">
    <div class="rb-spot">
      <span class="rb-txt">Tidak Sama Sekali</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rb-tab-active').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).data('value'));
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question does not mention that jquery is preferred or required, although it has a jQuery tag. In vanilla javascript, you can achieve this with:

```js
var value;
var active = document.querySelector('.rb-tab-active');
if (active) {
  var value = active.getAttribute('data-value');
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the div and use Jquery data() function or attr().

```
$(".rb-tab-active").data("value");
```

or

```
$(".rb-tab-active").attr("value");
```

Refer these..

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

If no jquery using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("rb-tab-active").getAttribute("data-value");
```